# How multiple reducers in Redux store communicate with the right action creators?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm completely new in learning `redux`. While working, I explored that when I have multiple `reducers` bundled in the `redux store (combineReducers)`, and I have multiple separate `action creators` and I use `useDispatch` to pass one specific `action creator` at a time, how redux knows to which `reducer` it should communicate? Why doesn't is mess with wrong `reducer`?

Answer (score 0):

Because [when you use `combineReducers`, *all* slice reducers get called with the same action](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#combining-reducers).

So, some slice reducers will look at the action and say "I don't care about this, return the existing state unchanged".  And other slice reducers *may* say "Oh, I need to return a new updated state value".

Comment: Thanks for your time. Can you please explain it more easily so that I can understand?

Comment: Every reducer will always be called with every action. Most actions are just ignored by all but one reducer.